# Number of ways to make collection of pairs?

Tags: graph-theory, combinations, binomial-distribution

If I have a graph composed of two communities of vertices, say divided into one community with 6 white vertices and another community of 6 black vertices. If I then pair the vertices off into 6 pairs at random, and then form an edge between each pair, the final graph will have 6 edges, with each vertex having a degree of 1.

If I then define a variable which keeps track of the number of edges which have one white vertex and one black vertex (edges with one end in each community), I am assuming it should follow a binomial distribution. However, I am having a hard time being able to demonstrate this, would someone be able to give me an insight?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit:

Sorry, in your question I missed the fact that your vertices had degree 1 after you chose your edges. So my answer is not valid in this case.

As paw88789 said in his answer, in this case the distribution is probably not binomial.

---

Suppose your graph $G = (V, E)$ has $|V| = N$, and $V = B \cup W$ where $B$ represents the set of black vertices, and $W$ represents the set of white vertices. Let $|B| = b$ and $|W| = w$ be the number of black vertices and the number of white vertices respectively (note that $b + w = N$). You want to place $M$ edges at random between your vertices.

Denote by $X$ the random variable counting the number of edges between $B$ and $W$. We will compute the expression $\mathbb{P}[X= k]$ which is the probability that there are $k$ edges (among $M$) between $B$ and $W$.

We start by computing the probability that an edge lies between $B$ and $W$. It is given by the probability that one end is in $B$ and the other end is in $W$. Hence it is given by $$p = \frac{b}{N} \cdot \frac{w}{N} = \frac{b \cdot w}{N^2}.$$
Now, we look at $\mathbb{P}[X=k]$. You have to choose $k$ edges from $M$, there are $M \choose k$ ways to do so. You want these $k$ edges to be between $B$ and $W$, hence the probability to have this is $p^k$. Moreover you want the $M-k$ remaining edges to be between two vertices in $B$ or two vertices in $W$. The probability to have this is $(1-p)^{M-k}$. Hence
$$\mathbb{P}[X = k] = \binom{M}{k}p^k(1-p)^{M-k}.  $$

So indeed, $X$ the variables that counts the edges between $B$ and $W$ follows a binomial distribution of parameters $M$ and $p$.

---

So in your example, keeping my notations:
\[\mathbb{P}[X = k] = \binom{6}{k} \left( \frac{6 \cdot 6}{12 \cdot 12} \right) ^k \left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\right)^{6-k} = \binom{6}{k} \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^k \left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{6-k}.\]

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway, it's helped me think a bit more clearly about the problem

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect it to be binomial because the 6 'trials' (pairing two vertices) are not independent.  For instance if the first three trials result in three black-black pairings, the remaining three must result in white-white pairings.